# Hibernate, Maps and HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

Can anybody tell me how maps are used in HQL.

The documentation only have examples like

```
From Student s WHERE s.courseScore['coursename'] = 'F'
```

As in, the keys are hard coded. Can anybody point me to some documentation on how to use this with actual class instances as keys? Something like,

```
From Course c, Student s JOIN s.courseInfo info WHERE info[c].score = 'F'
```

The above doesn't work, but I'm guessing there must be some way of doing it. I found out I can  use index() to get the keys from a Map property. Ala'

```
... WHERE index(info) = c
```

So I can check if a key is exits in the map, but how do I actually get a instance mapped key a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick

```
WHERE index(info) = c AND info.score = 'whatever'
```